# What is making the webbrowser close before it finishes?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the code bellow which I know has worked before but for some reason seems to be broken now. The code is mean't to open a search engine, search for a query and return a list of results by the `href` tag. The webbrowser will open and navigate to http://www.startpage.com success fully, it then puts the term I have entered at the bottom into the search box but then just closes the browser. No error, no links. Nothing.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.startpage.com"
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
    search_box = browser.find_element_by_id("query")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    try:
        links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='web_regular_results']//h3//a")
    except:
        links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3//a")
    results = []
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute("href")
        print(href)
        results.append(href)
    browser.close()
    return results

get_results("dog")
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this? Basically it gets to `search_box.submit()` then skips everything until `browser.close()`.

Comment: Thank you @Guy and @Zohair for the answers. I added both these into my project but it still does the same thing. I even tried just removing the `browser.close()` completely which got it to search for `dog` but returned nothing. I had originally just tried Safari and Firefox but even though it is deprecated I decided to try `PhantomJS` and for whatever reason that worked. I'm lost at this point but I didn't actually need it visually on the screen so using `PhantomJS` is not that bad.

Comment: Right before `results = []`, add a line `print(len(links))`... what gets printed? I bet it's `0`. Guy's answer should have fixed the problem if you implemented it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `find_element_by_xpath` (single WebElement) If `find_elements_by_xpath` won't find any results it won't throw an exception, it will return an empty list. `links` is empty so the `for` loop is never executed. You can change the `try except` to `if` condition, and check if it has values

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@class='web_regular_results']//h3//a")
if not links:
    links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3//a")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use browser close function within the function that you are testing. Instead you can use after the get_results("dog") function and keep the test logic away.

```
get_results("dog")
browser.close()
```

By doing this way selenium will complete the execution of the function first and then close the browser window.

The problem with your solution is that the method is returning the result set after the browser is closing the window due to which you are facing logical problem with your script.

Comment: Using `browser.close()` outside the function might be better practice, but it doesn't affect the results. The Python script is not dependent on the browser, it will continue.